# Meaning of "desperate picnic"

Tags: expressions

I've seen the expression "desperate picnic" whose exact meaning I've been unable to find in the Internet.

I thought it could be a common expression in English. The full sentence was:

> Dwarika's Hotel a safe haven thanks to dedicated staff that made a natural disaster feel like a desperate picnic in the garden.
>
> http://ireport.cnn.com/docs/DOC-1236810?ref=feeds%2Foncnn

Could you help me?

Comment: It's almost certainly a pun on 'desperate panic', comical because of incongruity.

Comment: Maybe a picnic in England (!).

Comment: I thought it could be a common expression in English. The full sentence was: "Dwarika's Hotel a safe haven thanks to dedicated staff that made a natural disaster feel like a desperate picnic in the garden". http://ireport.cnn.com/docs/DOC-1236810?ref=feeds%2Foncnn

Comment: You need to edit and  include this latest information in your question.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the entire text (including headline and author bio) of the "CNN iReport" that the OP refers to:

> **Dwarika's Hotel a safe haven thanks to dedicated staff that made a natural disaster feel like a desperate picnic in the garden**
>
> By NajibFaris  |  Posted 16 hours ago
>
> ***CNN PRODUCER NOTE** Jordanian NajibFaris, who lives in Dubai, was holidaying with his wife in the Nepalese capital of Kathmandu when the earthquake struck. "We had landed in Nepal the night before the earthquakes started, and luckily [later] made it out of there," he said. For safety reasons guests slept in the hotel garden under awnings, and he said hotel staff looked after all guests who had been affected. For the latest on the Nepal earthquake go to CNN.*
>
> Thanks to the unparalleled commitment of the Dwarika Hotel management and staff guest surviving the earthquakes at the property felt like it's a camping picnic in the hotel garden. The hotel staff did everything possible and beyond to ensure that each and every guest was rested, fed, and catered to to best possible.
>
> Over 80 guests (ourselves included) were made to feel part of the Dwarika's family during the rough hours of survival mode.

The story is essentially a report on morale at a particular hotel in Kathmandu by a Jordanian tourist in the aftermath of the terrible earthquakes that struck the region. This presumably rises to the level of reportable news because it is an eye-witness account—but there is nothing newsworthy about the story except insofar as it indicates that some parts of Kathmandu have so far survived the earthquakes without major damage and personal harm. I find it difficult to view this item as much more than an extra-long Twitter tweet.

The headline may well have been composed by CNN iReport staffers as part of their never-ending effort (in competition with every other news outlet on the Internet) to attract the eyeballs, if not the minds, of readers. The phrase "desperate picnic" does not match anything in the story (which uses the far more accurate phrase "camping picnic" at one point), which is notably devoid of any hint of desperation. Including "desperate" in the headline is completely unwarranted, in my opinion.

For an instance in which "desperate picnic" might make sense, consider this one:

> *Brad and Janet fear that their three-year relationship is crumbling. In a last ditch effort to overcome their estrangement and regain their lost happiness, they resolve to visit a nearby park, carrying a wicker basket laden with egg salad sandwiches, corn chips, vegetable sticks and cream-cheese dip, a fresh fruit medley, cookies, and a thermos of cold milk. Will they recapture the old magic? The stakes are high at their **desperate picnic***.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I see that the use of "desperate" was really out of place in that story. In fact, I was intrigued for two reasons: because four months ago I spent four days in that hotel and because her owner is the Honorary Consul of Spain in Kathmandu and the Consulate itself is installed on its premises.

Answer (score -1):

Finding the exact meaning presupposes that it has one to begin with. If someone has put the words together perhaps for the first time, we can't talk about an exact meaning, only about what (or even WTF) the author had in mind. Was the picnic desperate because subjected to gunfire? Is it the title of a slasher movie? Were the ants really, really hungry?  I'm sure *I* don't know. If it's a *stock* expression then it has passed me by as well as the Internet; perhaps it's a Millennial thing or the code of an in-group.